# paginacion manual en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, paginación

Hola tengo un problema al tratar de paginar con array con laravel, la pagina 1 me la muestra sin problema, pero cuando paso a otra me manda exepcion sin ninguna ayuda.

//controller

```
         if($request['marcasvehiculos']=='Marca' and $request['tipovehiculo']!='Tipo de Vehiculo' and $request['modelo']!='Modelo'){ 
         $busqueda = DB::table('vehiculos')
        ->join('marcasvehiculos', 'vehiculos.id_marcasvehiculos', '=', 'marcasvehiculos.id')
        ->join('tipovehiculo', 'vehiculos.id_tipovehiculo', '=', 'tipovehiculo.id')
        ->join('usuariosvehiculos', 'vehiculos.id_usuariosvehiculos', '=', 'usuariosvehiculos.id')
        ->select('vehiculos.*','marcasvehiculos.nombre as nombremarca','tipovehiculo.nombre as nombretipove','usuariosvehiculos.nombre as nombreusu','vehiculos.id as idvehiculo')
        ->where('vehiculos.id_tipovehiculo', '=', $request['tipovehiculo']  )
        ->where('vehiculos.modelo', '=', $request['modelo']  )
        ->where('vehiculos.estado', '=', 1)
        ->get();

        $data=array();
        $i=0;
        foreach ($busqueda as $key) {
           $busqimag =  Fotosvehiculos::where('id_vehiculos','=',$key->id)->get();
           $data[$i]['nombremarca']=$key->nombremarca;
           $data[$i]['nombretipove']=$key->nombretipove;
           $data[$i]['nombreusu']=$key->nombreusu;
           $data[$i]['kilometraje']=$key->kilometraje;
           $data[$i]['zona_influencia']=$key->zona_influencia;
           $data[$i]['recorrido_mensual']=$key->recorrido_mensual;
           $data[$i]['modelo']=$key->modelo; 
           $data[$i]['idvehiculo']=$key->idvehiculo; 
           $data[$i]['estado']=$key->estado; 
           $j=0;
           foreach ($busqimag as $key1) {
              $data[$i]['fotos'][$j]=$key1->imagen; 
              $j++;
           }
           $i++; 
        }
    }


    $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();
    $itemCollection = collect($data);
    $perPage = 3;
    $currentPageItems = $itemCollection->slice(($currentPage * $perPage) - $perPage, $perPage)->all();
    $paginatedItems= new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageItems , count($itemCollection), $perPage);
    $paginatedItems->setPath($request->url());

    return view('principal',['data' =>$paginatedItems]);
```

// vista

@if(count($data)>0)

### Resultados de la busqueda

```
  <div class="companies">
    @for($i=0;$i < count($data);$i++)
        <div class="company-list">
           <div class="row">

              <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                 <div class="company-logo">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                       <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="3000" id="myCarousel">
                          <div class="carousel-inner">
                             @for($j=0; $j < count($data[$i]['fotos']) ;$j++)
                             @if($j==0)
                             <div class="item active">
                                @else
                                <div class="item">
                                   @endif
                                   <div class="img-responsive" alt=""><a href="#"><img src="http://anunciaygana.com/fotosvehiculos/{{ $data[$i]['fotos'][$j] }}" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                   </div>
                                </div>
                                @endfor
                             </div>
                             <a class="left carousel-control hide" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                             <a class="right carousel-control hide" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
                    <div class="company-content">
                       <h5>Kilometraje: {{ $data[$i]['kilometraje'] }}  -  Modelo: {{ $data[$i]['modelo']}}  <input type="button" style="color: #ffffff; background-color: #ff7400" class="btn seub-btn" onclick="location.href='{{URL::to('detalles/'.$data[$i]['idvehiculo'] )}}';" value="Detalles" /></h5>
                       <p>
                          <span class="company-name"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>Zona: {{ $data[$i]['zona_influencia'] }}</span> 
                          <span class="company-location"><i class="fa fa-area-chart"></i>Recorrido: {{ $data[$i]['recorrido_mensual'] }} km</span>
                          <span class="package"><i class="fa fa fa-bus"></i>Tipo Vehiculo: {{ $data[$i]['nombretipove']}}</span>
                          <span class="package"><i class="fa fa-object-group"></i>Marca : {{ $data[$i]['nombremarca']}}</span>
                       </p>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           @endfor

           </div>
           <div class="text-center">
             {{ $data->links() }}
           </div>
        </div>

  @else
     <div class="row heading">
        <h2>Sin Resultados, Por favor busque en otras categorias</h2>
     </div>
  @endif


  </section>
```

//RUTAS

```
   Route::get('/','AppController@index')->name('index');
   Route::get('registrov','AppController@registrov')->name('Registro de 
   vehiculos');
   Route::get('registrou','AppController@registrou')->name('Registro de 
   usuarios');
   Route::post('r-usuarios', 'AppController@storeusuarios')- 
   >name('almacenamiento de usuario');
   Route::get('login','AppController@login')->name('Login')->name('login');
   Route::post('principal','AppController@principal')->name('busqueda');
   Route::post('r-vehiculos', 'AppController@storevehiculos')- 
   >name('almacenamiento de vehiculos');
   Route::get('detalles/{id}','AppController@detalles')->name('detalles');
   Route::get('adminp','AppController@adminp')->name('vehiculos 
   pendientes');
   Route::get('admina','AppController@admina')->name('Administrador 
   autorizados');
   Route::get('autorizar/{id}','AppController@autorizar')- 
   >name('autorizar');
   Route::get('rechazar/{id}','AppController@rechazar')->name('rechazar');
```

esta es la vista sin problemas al iniciar la pagina, pero cuando le doy en la pagina 2 me manda la otra pantalla con el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta con `{!! $data->fragment('hash')->appends(request()->query())->links('pagination::bootstrap-4') !!}`

Comment: no funciona me sale el mismo mensaje

Comment: {{ $data->links() }} esto al final donde lo tenias declarado?

Comment: lo tengo declara en la vista

Comment: si gustas mira la pagina online http://anunciaygana.com, y oprimer el boton de buscar sin ningun filtro y veras el resultado

Comment: No tiene que ver con el tema de rutas? Podrías mostrar las rutas de tu `web.php`? por lo menos las asociadas a la vista principal. Lo pregunto así porque no he trabajado con ese tipo de paginacion pero viendo las otras descripciones del error, pareciera un tema de ruta

Comment: esta es mi ruta, Route::post('principal','AppController@principal')->name('busqueda');

Comment: `http://anunciaygana.com/principal?page=2` necesitas una ruta `GET` que reciba ese parámetro `page` pero no se como funciona esa paginacion. Espero alguien pueda ayudarte.. Edita tu pregunta y agrega esa ruta a la pregunta.

Comment: Me manda a la pagina principal sin errores

Comment: porque en ves de un for, usas un foreach?

Comment: pues eso no hay porblema yo lo cambio por un for y ya te confirmo si algo afecta

Comment: ya lo modifique con el ciclo for y no hay ninguna diferencia en el resultado

Answer (score 0):

El error que tienes actualmente se debe a que intentas acceder a una ruta que solo esta disponible en POST mediante un GET.

Añadiendo esta ruta se deberia solucionar tu error.

```
Route::get('principal','AppController@principal')
```

Aunque te recomiendo que el formulario de la pagina principal también envié los datos por GET, si no al paginar se va a perder el filtro.

Comment: Hola buenos dias, me funciono, pero no se como enviar los parametros tambien por get sin dañar el metodo post

Comment: Buenos dias, hay algún motivo en especial por el que tengas que utilizar el POST?

Comment: pues la verdad lo puedo cambiar sin problemas, la inquietud es como quedaria la ruta, por get ya que cuando le doy clic me manda algo como esto? http://anunciaygana.com/principal?page=2

Comment: La ruta quedaria igual que siempre, los parametros get no afectan a la ruta. Otra cosa seria que incluyeses rutas con parametros que seria del palo ".com/principal/2", en ese caso la ruta en Laravel seria 'principal/{page}'